# iTunes screenshots for ad-supported Apps?

Tags: itunes, app-store-connect

I have a paid App and I'm introducing a free, ad-supported version of this Ad. There are AdMob banners at the bottom of most screens.

What should I use as screenshots in iTunes?

- Screenshots with actual ads?
- Screenshots with empty space where the ads are supposed to be (taken in airplane mode)?
- Screenshots from the paid version, without ads and with more data on the screen?

I've browsed through quite a lot of ad-supported Apps in iTunes. The vast majority of them don't show any ads in their screenshots and don't have empty ad space either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't modify my screenshots. I almost feel like I'm tricking the user into downloading my app if I remove the ads. A lot of people feel differently though.

Comment: Does this mean that you advertise some arbitrary product (the one that happened to be shown when you took your screenshots) in iTunes?